# Why won't curl recognise a self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: curl, nginx, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I copied the PEM file into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ and ran update-ca-certificates, and I verified that the resulting certificate is now included in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt which is the file printed by curl-config --ca.  I also verified that the certificate printed by openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 was identical to my PEM file.  And yet I continue to get the "error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" message.  This happens even if I use curl's --cacert option as described at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html to tell it what certificate to use.

It works if I disable certificate verification altogether with curl -k, but I don't want to do that because I'm trying to write a test harness that's supposed to test the SSL properly.

It works fine if I access the same URL in lynx, which normally complains if there are any SSL errors.  But I can't just use Lynx for this test harness, unless I can find some way of making Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient use Lynx instead of libcurl.  And it doesn't seem to make any sense that installing the self-signed certificate satisfies Lynx but not curl.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a Vagrant-powered VirtualBox; it has curl 7.22.0.  The SSL terminating proxy is nginx/1.3.13 running on the same machine, and the domain name is pointed to 127.0.0.1 by an entry in /etc/hosts.

Any clues on what might be the problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If we use [`cURL`](https://curl.haxx.se/) to retrieve a `HTTPS` site that is not using a [CA-signed certificate](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15189.difference-between-self-signed-ssl-certificate-authority.aspx), the following problem occurs:

```
curl https://example.selfip.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

While we can simply overcome this using the `-k` option, there's a safer and lasting solution, i.e.:

**Step 1**
Identify which directory your `OpenSSL` installation uses.

```
openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

**Step 2**
Change to that directory and list the directory contents. You should see a directory called `certs`.

```
cd /usr/lib/ssl && ls -al
```

**Step 3**
Change to that directory.

```
cd certs
```

List the directory contents. You should see from the symlinks that the certificates are actually stored in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`.

**Step 4**
Change to `/usr/share/ca-certificates` directory and **add you self-signed certificate there, (ex: your.cert.name.crt)**

**Step 5**
Change to `/etc` directory and edit the file `ca-certificates.conf`.

```
root@ubuntu:# cd /etc
root@ubuntu:# nano ca-certificates.conf
```

Add `your.cert.name.crt` to the file (`ca-certificates.conf`) and save it.

**Last Step:**

Execute the program `update-ca-certificates –fresh`.
Note: You might like to backup `/etc/ssl/certs` before executing the command.

```
root@ubuntu:# update-ca-certificates --fresh
Clearing symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs...done.
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs....done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

Test with curl on your target HTTPS site and it should work now.

[Source](http://www.onlinesmartketer.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/)

Comment: Centos:
Install the ca-certificates package: `yum install ca-certificates`
Enable the dynamic CA configuration feature: `update-ca-trust force-enable`
Add it as a new file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/: `cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
Use command: `update-ca-trust extract`
(Thanks https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html)

Comment: In my case I also had to add `example.com` to `/etc/hosts`. Posted an answer on it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58051724/5153500