# curl self-signed certificate web service over SSL

Tags: rest, curl, self-signed

Hi I am having a big headache trying to curl a REST web service I created locally over SSL. **I keep getting the message "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate**
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option."

Here the steps I followed

1. created my own CA certificate with OpenSSL private certificate and key pair
   OpenSSL req -x509 -new -config c:\X509CA\openssl.cfg -days 365 -out c:\X509CA\ca\private_ca.pem -keyout c:\X509CA\ca\private_ca_pk.pem
   my CN: RESTfulCustomer
2. created the keystore and mycert.pem
   keytool -genkey -validity 365 -alias myalias -keypass password -keystore myKeyStore.jks -storepass password
   used the same CN as above
3. Created a certificate signing request
   keytool -certreq -alias myalias -file myCert_csr.pem -keypass password -keystore myKeyStore.jks -storepass password
4. Signed the CSR with
   openssl 
   ca -config c:\X509CA\openssl.cfg -days 365 -in c:\path\to\key_store\myCert_csr.pem -out c:\path\to\key_store\myCert.pem
5. Converted to PEM format - Convert the signed certificate, CertName.pem, to PEM only format, as follows:
   Openssl x509 -in c:\path\to\key_store\myCert.pem -out c:\path\to\key_store\myCert.pem -outform PEM
6. concatenated the CA certificate file and the certName.pem
   copy myCert.pem + c:\X509CA\ca\new_ca.pem myCert.chain
7. Updated keystore with the full certificate chain - Update the keystore, CertName.jks, by importing the full certificate chain for the certificate, as follows:
   keytool -import -file myCert.chain -keypass password -keystore myKeyStore.jks -storepass password
   finally imported it into firefox, updated my server.xml apache tomacat 7 starts ok and I could navigate to my ssl webpage with no problems. Curl does not work without using --insecure. My Curl command
   curl -v --cacert ca.pem  https://`localhost`:8443/RESTfulCustomer/customers.json

**the curl command above gives me the message "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate"**

Running the Curl command for http//`localhost`:8080/RESTfuCustomer.customers.json with ssl disabled works fine.

I imported the ca.pem into myKeyStore.jks and restarted Apache. 
Environemnt windows 7,apache tomcat 7, spring security 3.1, curl 7.30.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7

any help would be really appreciated
thanks

Comment: Consider editing your question in order to improve readability.  Feel free to use the bold features to highlight important details or perhaps what your question is.  This will get you answers fasters.  Other than that, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this in the future, I had to create the cert for `localhost.com` and add it to the end of my `/etc/hosts` file like this and then `curl --cacert cert.crt https://localhost.com`.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost.com
```

If you are not on linux or mac, you can try this in a docker container which will have `/etc/hosts`.

I don't know why it wouldn't work with `localhost` as domain name, but curl would keep complaining about self-signed certs. Might have something to do with either docker networking or something special about the localhost keyword.

Answer (score -1):

please refer to that following answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28927268/1290438

to sum up:

```
% openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/p' | grep -m1 -B-1 -- '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'  > cert.pem
% curl --cacert cert.pem https://example.com
```

and tada, you connect securely to a self-signed website.